# how to merge similar observations by key attributes in json python

Tags: python, json

Im working with JSON in python, It new to me, and im trying to merge similar observations by key attributes.
The JSON looks like this:

```
tempads=[
['doron-2020-026', ['19.0.1']],
['doron-2020-026', ['18.0.6']],
['doron-2020-023', ['19.0.0']],
['doron-2020-023', ['18.0.5']],
['doron-2020-023', ['17.0.7']]
]
```

I tried to create a list with unique observations using this:

```
    for tempad in tempads:
    ads.append(tempad[0])
ads = list(dict.fromkeys(ads))
```

the output is:

```
['doron-2020-026', 'doron-2020-023']
```

then I tried to look for that list values and to add to them the observations
but for some reason, it's only giving me back the latest one:

```
for ad in ads:
    for i in range(0,len(tempads)-1):
        if ad==tempads[i][0]:
            ad=[ad,tempads[i][1]]
            newads.append(ad)
print(newads)

[
['doron-2020-026', ['19.0.1']],
['doron-2020-023', ['19.0.0']]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a groupby.

Using `itertools.groupby`. Note this works only if the list is ordered.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

tempads=[
    ['doron-2020-026', ['19.0.1']],
    ['doron-2020-026', ['18.0.6']],
    ['doron-2020-023', ['19.0.0']],
    ['doron-2020-023', ['18.0.5']],
    ['doron-2020-023', ['17.0.7']]
    ]

result = [[k, [n for _, i in v for n in i]] for k, v in groupby(tempads, lambda x: x[0])]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['doron-2020-026', ['19.0.1', '18.0.6']],
 ['doron-2020-023', ['19.0.0', '18.0.5', '17.0.7']]]
```

---

If the list is unordered use a simple `dict`

**Ex:**

```
result = {}
for k, v in tempads:
    result.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
```

**Output:**

```
{'doron-2020-023': ['19.0.0', '18.0.5', '17.0.7'],
 'doron-2020-026': ['19.0.1', '18.0.6']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this by using the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

tempads=[
    ['doron-2020-026', ['19.0.1']],
    ['doron-2020-026', ['18.0.6']],
    ['doron-2020-023', ['19.0.0']],
    ['doron-2020-023', ['18.0.5']],
    ['doron-2020-023', ['17.0.7']]
]

d = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in tempads:
    d[key].extend(value)

print(d)
```

gives:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
'doron-2020-026': ['19.0.1', '18.0.6'], 
'doron-2020-023': ['19.0.0', '18.0.5', '17.0.7']
})
```

which can be used like a normal dictionary.

---

Of course you could convert it back into a list like this:

```py
lst = [[k, v] for k, v in d.items()]
```